# Spring WebClient is blocking the thread

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, nonblocking, spring-webclient

Spring WebClient is supposed to be non-blocking ([reference doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.0.19.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client)). But when I was trying it out in a sample demo code, it was blocking the main thread.

When I run the below code I get the following output:

```
main: main
runBlocking: main
async: main
304 //length of output
wait over in 2346
after async
```

I was expecting that "after async" would print before "304" (output of API call) as the API should not block the main thread and main() function should carry on with code that is after the async block.

Main Code::

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.delay
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient
import reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient
import kotlin.system.measureTimeMillis


fun main() {
    val httpClient = HttpClient.create()
    val client: WebClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("https://postman-echo.com/get?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2")
        .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
        .build()
    println("main: " + Thread.currentThread().name)
    runBlocking {
        println("runBlocking: " + Thread.currentThread().name)
        async {
            println("async: " + Thread.currentThread().name)
            val time = measureTimeMillis {
                val out = client.get().retrieve().bodyToMono(String::class.java).block()
                println(out.length)
            }
            println("wait over in $time")
        }
        delay(1)
        println("after async")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `.awaitBody<T>()` instead of `.block()` (which is blocking operation)

Something like:

```
val out = client.get().retrieve().awaitBody<String>()
```

Comment: Issue was with my dependencies. I thought I was pointing to latest spring-webflux but  was actually pointing to spring-webflux - 5.1.8.RELEASE and awaitBody is added after 5.2. I was trying to use auto-suggest and I wasn't getting any other suggestion apart from block so thought that would be the only method available in latest release.

Works as expected after using awaitBody.